# Difference between system_tests and test_framework

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails configuring guides, https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-rails-components, under section 3.3, there are a list of methods that can be used in config generators block. Among them are system_tests and test_framework, which are defined as follows:

> system_tests defines which integration tool to use to generate system
> tests. Defaults to :test_unit
>
> test_framework defines which test framework to use. Defaults to false
> and will use minitest by default.

The question is what's the difference between them, cause integration tool and test framework are both synonyms for me. Besides test_unit and minitest, based in my researchs on Google, are both test frameworks, and minitest is kind of a test_unit replacement.

You migth also have noted that in test_framework definition is written: "Defaults to false and will use minitest by default". The only left question is, what?!!!

If it defaults to false, shouldn't it mean that no test framework will be used? This assertion is completely illogical.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it is confusing how they write it.

I think when they say "system test," they are referring to the popular "integration tests" or "feature tests" which as you know, interacts with the browser. So they're saying they will use test unit which will probably use capybara driver under the hood.

I think when they say "test framework," they are saying you could use something like rspec to write your tests instead of minitest.

It will probably help if you think of integration tool as the under-the-hood driver such as capybara.

Sorry I'm on mobile app and cannot see rest of your question so I will submit then update if needed.